# Добавить поочередно каждый элемент масива в новою строку таблицы

Tags: php, mysql, массивы

Из введенных пользователем данных создаеться массив. В таблице базы данных надо записать каждый элемент этого массива в один и тот же столбец, но в новой строке.

Например:

```
$array_m = (1, 5, 3, 8, 125, 6);
```

Надо создать 6 строк, где в столбце num каждой строки  будет записан следующий элемент.
Пробовал сделать так:

```
    $query_num = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM `num`");
echo $mysqli->error;
global $row_num;
$row_num = $query_num->fetch_assoc();
$id = $accessed['id'];


function create_t($num, $num_of_members){
    $mysqli = $GLOBALS['mysqli'];
    $mysqli -> query("CREATE TABLE `mybase`.`lottery_$num` ( `num` INT(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `members` INT(16) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`num`), UNIQUE (`members`)) ENGINE = MyISAM;");
    $mysqli -> query("UPDATE `num` SET  `num_t` =  `num_t` + 1");



    $i = 1;
    $array_m = array();
    while ($i <= $num_of_members) {
        $array_m[$i] = $i;
        $i++;
    }

    foreach($array_m as $value){
    echo $value;
    $mysqli -> query("INSERT INTO `mybase`.`lottery_$num` (`num`) VALUES ($value)");
}

}

if (isset($_POST['create_table'])) { //инпут и кнопка
create_t($row_num['num_t'], $_POST['num_of_members']);
$_POST['create_table'] = null;
$mysqli -> query("UPDATE  `mybase`.`users` SET  `is_member` =  '2' WHERE  `users`.`id` = '$id';");
header('Location:redirect.php');
exit;
}
```

Но создается каждый раз не введенное количество строк, а только одна.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте переделать как-то так:

```
$array_m = (1, 5, 3, 8, 125, 6); //записываем элементы массива построчно в БД

function create_t($num, $array_m){
  $mysqli = $GLOBALS['mysqli']; //оставил ваш код без изменений
  $mysqli -> query("CREATE TABLE `mybase`.`lottery_$num` ( `num` INT(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `members` INT(16) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`num`), UNIQUE (`members`)) ENGINE = MyISAM;");
  $mysqli -> query("UPDATE `num` SET  `num_t` =  `num_t` + 1");

  foreach($array_m as $value){ 
  //перебирая массив через  foreach будет однозначный вызов mysqli->query 
  //для каждого элемента
    echo $value;
    $mysqli -> query("INSERT INTO `mybase`.`lottery_$num` (`num`) VALUES ($value)");
  }
}
```